# TinyMCE v4 Button Label remaining static

Tags: tinymce-4

I am trying to customise a button with multiple entries and multiple sub menus. I have managed to do this satisfactorily with the following code but would like the button label to remain the same whatever menu item is chosen. The listbox is the only method that I have been able to get this effect but fail on other types of button that do retain the label.

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
toolbar: "mybutton",
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'Test Menu',
        icon: false,
        onselect: function(e) {
            editor.insertContent(this.value());
        },
        values: [
            {text:'Menu No 1', menu:[
        {text:'Sub Menu 1',value:'Some text for sub menu 1'},
        {text:'Sub Menu 2',value:'Some text for sub menu 2'}
    ]},
            {text:'Menu No 2', menu:[
        {text:'Sub Menu 3',value:'Some text for sub menu 3'},
        {text:'Sub Menu 4',value:'Some text for sub menu 4'}
    ]}


        ],
    });
} });
```

Any help most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem I solved it with resetting the text in onselect:

```
    onselect: function(e) {
        editor.insertContent(this.value());
        this.text('Test Menu');
    }
```